# Heroku Connect: Extend Error Log Duration, and UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I'm not too familiar with Heroku Connect so excuse me if these are newbie questions.

1. Is there a way to view Salesforce Error logs beyond a day old? I get the email notification for errors writing to Salesforce but if I don't check on them within a day, I can't access them anymore.
2. If the problem is "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW", should we configure for the Retry stated here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-faq#can-i-retry-records-that-failed-to-write-to-salesforce ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of writes toward Salesforce, all the changes are kept into Postgres: on the _trigger_log table once occurred and then moved to _trigger_log_archive once processed. On demo plan these records are preserved up to 7 days, on paid plan up to 30 days. You can then look at the archive table to have more insights of the failure and manually resubmit the change, as explained in the link you have mentioned.